# Как выбрать из таблицы строки удовлетворяющие одновременно двум значениям колонки?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица *article_param* - в которой храню соответствия

- товар -> его характеристика

К товару может быть привязано множество характеристик.

Нужно иметь возможность выбирать:

- все товары у которых есть параметр `15` *И* параметр `16`

```
----------------------------
id | id_article | id_param
1        1           15
2        2           15
3        2           16
4        3           21
----------------------------
```

Как на чистом *sql* написать запрос - не представляю, в голову лезут велосипеды с пхп и циклами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое простое примерно так:

```
select A.*
  from article_param A, article_param B
 where A.id_article=B.id_article and A.id_param=15 and B.id_param=16
```

Для случая, когда во время разработки не известно, сколько параметров будет в запросе, но известно в момент выполнения то что то типа:

```
select id_article
  from article_param
 where id_param in(15,16,17)
 group by id_article
 having count(1)=3
```

Где `3` - количество искомых атрибутов

P.S. наличие колонки `id` в вашей таблице сбивает с толку, если это у вас таблица в которой хранятся параметры для объектов с `id_article` и виды этих параметров `ip_param`, а значение параметра еще где то рядом лежит, то этой таблице сурогатный ключ `id` не нужен. Его можно убрать и в качестве первичного ключа использовать `(id_param, id_article)`, что экономит место и заодно обеспечивает уникальность конкретного параметра для конкретного `article`. Ну и плюс к этому, наличие такого индекса как этот ключ как раз обеспечит быстрый поиск вышеуказанными запросами

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь! Ваш второй пример - как раз то, что нужно. Уникальную колонку ID - по инерции всем таблицам добавляю. Конкретно в этой ситуации никакого функционала на ней нет.

Comment: @librown Тогда начните избавляться от инерции :) если связку (id_param, id_article) не сделать уникальной, то случайно попавшие  2х одинаковых param для одного article сделает такой запрос некорректным